# MS SQL database Admin/IDE

Tags: mysql, sql-server, visual-studio, interface, admin

I'm using MS SQL for a project, but have always used MySql in the past.  MySql has a really nice interface which lets you build queries, offers help, backup etc.

What free programs are there for MS Sql that can do this.  I'm currently a student so I have free access to MS Sql but the only interface I have for it right now is Visual Studio 2008.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en) is available in an "Express" edition as well. It's a separate download from SQL Server Express, though.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Management Studio should come with SQL Server and is quite a nice and easy to use administrator tool.

- create DBs, tables etc.
- control permissions
- run queries
- and much much more